# Change size of safe area of view controller in Storyboard in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard, safearea

Somehow the safe area for a view controller that I have placed in a storyboard has picked up an odd starting value for Y of 88. This is pushing everything linked to it, mainly a tableview down.

[image]

There are a few other weird things about the view controller. If I leave it on Fixed, the viewcontroller has a height of 896. I can change to freeform and then manually reduce the size but that fails to change the safe area and everything is still pushed down. If I change to freeform and back to fixed, the VC goes back to 896.

I have tried unchecking safe area and then rechecking but same problem recurs.

Would appreciate any suggestions on how to resolve this.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, 88 sounds like navigation bar (44) + top safearea (44), have you embedded a navigation controller to this viewcontroller from storyboard? If so, the height of navigation controller will be carried over.

[image]

Comment: Yes it is embedded in a Navigation Controller. However, I normally do it that way so that there is space for the back button. Could something be checked that shouldn't be. Also I tried just disabling the safe area and the table is still dropped down. Also I created a whole new view controller and the same thing happened.

Comment: But your job (@user6631314) is to tell _us_ how to make the same thing happen.